# javascript function to create url using the parameter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

Here is a js function i have in which I would like to make a xmlhttp.open call using the parameter value

```
  <script>
  function showStudents(str) {
      if (str == "") {
          document.getElementById("stuList").innerHTML ="";
          return;
      } else {
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        //code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      }else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
              document.getElementById("stuList").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
          }
          else if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 404) {
              document.getElementById("stuList").innerHTML = 'Invalid URL';
          }

    }

    xmlhttp.open("POST", "<?php echo site_url("/rhadmin/testing/"); ?> + str ",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
```

If the value of the 'str' parameter is 6 - then the final url should be http://localhost/rhadmin/testing/6

What do I need to do to get this?

Appreciate any help on this.
Thank you.

Comment: what does it do now? Errors thrown in console would be a good place to start

Comment: I'm assuming str is a javascript variable and so it shouldn't be inside the quotes. `"<?php echo site_url("/rhadmin/testing/"); ?>" + str`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xmlhttp.open("POST", "<?php echo site_url("/rhadmin/testing/"); ?>"+str,true);`

Comment: Adding an explanation of what is/was wrong will help this answer. Posting just code, even if correcting the mistake, is generally frowned upon because it isn't always obvious what the problem was. Just that this *might* fix it. OP doesn't learn how to fix it. Even just a simple explanation like I posted above is better than nothing.